# How to scroll the UITableviewcell scroll up when the keyboard appears?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, scroll, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table View scroll when text field begin editing iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029399/table-view-scroll-when-text-field-begin-editing-iphone)

I have loaded many UITextFields in UITableview. Maximum i have 15 UITextFields in UITableView cells. I want to move(Scroll) up the the Cell when the Keyboard/UIActionSheet(UIPickerView) appears. Please suggest/guide me any sample code to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for all my friends to answer my question and clarify the doubts. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try below code in `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing` ....

```
self.tblView.frame= CGRectMake(self.tblView.frame.origin.x, self.tblView.frame.origin.y, self.tblView.frame.size.width, self.tblView.frame.size.height - 190);
NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:nIndex inSection:nSectionIndex];
[self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mitesh Khatri. It works very fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is nIndex and nSectionIndex?

Comment: nIndex is a row no or a integer value.

Comment: it is not the good answer, because let say the row you want to edit is in the last row. the scrollToRowAtIndexPath cannot work in that way

Comment: @justicepenny, than what you suggest for the last row? please help.

Comment: One more thing after change you need to reset the frame of tableview

Comment: @MiteshKhatri And what about `DidEndEditing`

Answer (score 11):

You can use the sample code to take some hint.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

I have used it in my projects as well.Hope it helps

Comment: Was easy to use the TableView sub class in this project to get my table scrolling correctly when the keyboard opened.

Comment: Thanks! that thing should be added to pods!

Answer (score 5):

Check out the below link from apple documentation with complete explanation  and required code

They have talked about for registering for the keyboard appear and disappear notification and alter the rect of your underlaying `UIView` in the notification method for more go through the below URL.

[Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)