# view scroll when key boards appears ios

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios5

I have table view with search bar and search delegate added. When I try to search,my view scrolls up and my navigation bar is no more displayed. Is there any way to over ride so that the navigation bar is not hidden??

This screen shot is initial screen

[image: This screen shot is initial screen]

this screen shot is when searching

[image: this screen shot is the one when searching]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit this question. It may help you a little bit. 
[How to scroll the UITableviewcell scroll up when the keyboard appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338737/how-to-scroll-the-uitableviewcell-scroll-up-when-the-keyboard-appears)

Thanks.