# UITableViewController not scrolling view when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a `UITableViewController` with around 20 static cells, some of these cells have `UITextField`s within them and some are just for selecting with a checkmark.  The table is about 1.5 views worth so scrolling is required to get at the lower text fields.

When I click within a textfield at the bottom of the table the keyboard pops up as it should but this then appears over the cell/textfield.

I was under the impression (From Apple docs and elsewhere) that the `UITableViewController` class handles scrolling of the view automatically when a keyboard appears in any orientation and shifts the tableview up so that the cell is visible, this isn't happening though.

IOS 5.1, iPad Portrait.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll the UITableviewcell scroll up when the keyboard appears?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338737/how-to-scroll-the-uitableviewcell-scroll-up-when-the-keyboard-appears)

Comment: Not a dup IMO, this one deals with Static Cell TVC's

Comment: The link that Rishi pointed too actually worked for my static table content.  But like I said, I though this was meant to work automatically when using UITableViewController without the need to programatically manage scrolling.

Comment: Ive found the cause of the problem.  My app launches a popover, in that popover there is a button that open a full screen model view UITableViewController which contains the table.  If I don't use a popover in the heirarchy then the TVC will auto scroll the table when a field is clicked, with the popover back in the hierarchy then  it loses the scroll functionality of the TVC.  Not sure how to fix this yet but its some progress.

Answer (score 88):

Make sure that if you are overriding `viewWillAppear` that you call

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

If you don't, the Scroll View will not scroll up properly.

**Swift**

```
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
```

Comment: This worked for me (and I should have been calling this anyway). Thanks.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much, I thought I would never make it work automatically again)

Comment: You know what...You are God for me !

Comment: ThnQ @EIJay It saved my time

Comment: Great... It's so easy and sometimes you still forget it

Comment: I have a TBVController as subview in a container view...and I thought it was not going to work anymore but your solution is a miracle. Wish I could vote up more! Thanks!

Comment: That's a good example why you should always call super, especially if this explicitly specified in the documentation ))

Comment: you saved me a major headache

Comment: I've been a programmer for over 20 years now. Sometimes I make silly mistakes and then keep looking for the bigger problem. Thanks for saving my life :)

Comment: Damn, that is a heck of an answer. I was about to report it as a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found non of these answers to be correct.  After a while, I notice that if you push a controller it won't work ... but if you present it modally.. the table will automatically scroll to the used textfield.

Hope that saves time and stress to anyone.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I am using a container view.

Answer (score 2):

> If the auto scroll of UITableViewController doesn't work with the
>   UITextFields in cells or scroll weirdly, do these steps. **Swift 5 iOS
>   13.2 tested 100%**

First implement **viewWillAppear** but don't call **super.viewWillAppear** (this will **stop** auto scroll)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

}
```

Then let's do the scroll **manually**.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  //Notification center observers
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                             name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

//keybord show action
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: notification.getKeyBoardHeight, right: 0)
}
//keyboard hide action
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

extension Notification {

    var getKeyBoardHeight: CGFloat {

        let userInfo: NSDictionary = self.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardFrame: NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        return keyboardRectangle.height
    }

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself. I just converted my view controller from a UIViewController to a UITableViewController in addition to adding the `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` call, you will need to remove these lines:

`[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
 [self.tableView setDelegate:self];`

As they are no longer needed and setDelegate interferes with the keyboard scrolling behavior.