# UITableViewController loses scroll functionality if presented by a popover as model

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, scroll, uitableview, popover

Any reason why a model tableview (UITableViewController) is not scrolling a table when the keyboard appears ONLY if presented by a popover controller?

I basically have a popover menu with a button that opens a model Tableview fullscreen, text fields within rows at the bottom of the table get hidden by the keyboard when tapped.

This is not the same as a UIView or Scrollview where you have to manage scrolling manually.  The UITableViewController has this functionality built in, it just doesn't work if there is a popover controller somewhere back down the hierarchy.

Sample project: www.geoffcoope.co.uk/ios/testTVCScrolling.zip

Thanks
Geoff

Comment: Are you altering this thing's frame when the keyboard appears?

Comment: Nope, not touching the frame.

Comment: So you just need the cells to get out of the way of the keyboard?

Comment: do you have the same issue like your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243712/uitableviewcontroller-not-scrolling-view-when-keyboard-appears

Comment: Please put a screen shot or some codes.

Comment: Will upload a mini demo project showing the problem.  Just need to find my ftp details

Comment: Project uploaded and adding link to file in original message.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening? Your issue seems very similar to [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901754/uitableviewcontroller-auto-scrolling-stops-taking-into-account-keyboard-when-sho).

Comment: Also, your sample project download link is broken and I can't duplicate your described behavior in my own testing.

Answer (score 1):

Either your UITableView is sending its delegate method requests to the popover's view controller instead of your UITableView controller, or your UITableView's delegate is set to nil.  Look where you are instantiating your TableView and make sure you are setting the delegate property correctly.

Comment: Of course, if you post your code we will be happy to help you find the bug more specifically.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case :) triple checked it.  I will upload a mini sample project showing the problem.  Almost no code apart from rows/sections added to source.

Comment: Sample project uploaded: www.geoffcoope.co.uk/ios/testTVCScrolling.zip

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is with a way a storyboard's segue shows popover controllers. It looks like it is a common problem.

So, the easiest way to solve it, is to move the creation of your modal window inside a code. Something like that:

Inside your `ViewController.h` write

```
@property (strong) UIPopoverController * popoverController;
- (void) showNavigationController;
```

Inside your `ViewController.m` write

```
@synthesize popoverController;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]){
        if (popoverController) [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue * popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *) segue;
        popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    }
}

- (void) showNavigationController
{
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    popoverController = nil;

    UIStoryboard *ub = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *controller = [ub instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

then inside your MainStoryboard set identifier `navigationController` for your navigation controller and instead of segue on your "Show Table" button set a "touch up inside" delegate. This delegate will execute your `showNavigationController` method from `ViewController` (using a `NSNotificationCenter`, as example)