# UITableViewController auto-scrolling stops taking into account keyboard when shown from a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

When you subclass `UITableViewController`, you normally get certain behaviors "for free". For example, when a text field in your table view becomes first responder, the view controller automatically scrolls itself to ensure the field is fully visible.

However, when the table view controller is the detail view controller of a `UISplitViewController`, this auto-scrolling no longer takes into account the presence of the keyboard. The table view controller will still auto-scroll to keep the text field within the bounds of the screen, but it no longer scrolls to keep the field from being covered by the keyboard.

You can test this yourself by creating a new project using Xcode's "Master-Detail Application" template, and replacing the detail view controller with a table view controller that displays cells with text fields in them.

I would like to understand *why* the auto-scrolling stops accounting for the keyboard in this case, and if possible how to rectify that without having to duplicate the auto-scrolling functionality myself. BTW, this has nothing to do with overriding `viewWillAppear` (as in some other questions here about table view controller auto-scrolling).

Comment: So the wiring is probably hardcoded if it's a main `UITableViewController` the `UITableView` responds to the `UITextField` begin editing delegate call, but you losing that if your `UITableViewController` isn't the root controller.  I had no idea, but that doesn't surprise me.  That's why I never liked using `UITableViewController` in the first place and I think that means you need to write the `UITextField` wiring yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but this might help others who are having this issue. This happens to me as well when I added textfield in UITableViewCell. What I did was to remove

> superViewWilAppear:animated

line in viewWillAppear method.So the method looks like this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //[superViewWilAppear:animated];
     Your rest of code
}
```

But what this does is it removes the auto scrolling all together and you have to manage the scrolling of UITableView when textField starts editing. Don't know if this solved your problem but it will save you the trouble of considering keyboard height for different devices and its better to manage on your own. Also I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but it worked for me.