# Any reason a UITableViewController doesn't scroll the active textfield up when the keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitableview, uikeyboard

I have a UITableViewController that contains tables with cells that have a UITextField.  When the keyboard comes up to add or edit text in those textfields, those fields must move up so they are not obscured by the keyboard.  This should be handled automatically by the UITableViewController:

from [Apple:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW7)

> Note: A table view controller supports inline editing of table view
>   rows; if, for example, rows have embedded text fields in editing mode,
>   it scrolls the row being edited above the virtual keyboard that is
>   displayed.

Could the problem be that I am using a SplitViewController, with the UITableViewController on the right side (the larger split) and another view on the left split.

What am I missing?  Are there only certain situations in which the UITableViewController will handle this and not others?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the view itself a subclass of UITableViewController, or do you have a table view embedded in a UIView?

Comment: The tableView is the default tableView of the tableViewController.  It is not embedded in any other view.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same issue. In my case I had forgotten to call:

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

See: [UITableViewController not scrolling view when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243712/uitableviewcontroller-not-scrolling-view-when-keyboard-appears)

Comment: happening even after i called super.viewwillappear :-(

Comment: I haven't worked with iOS in a long time. I imagine some things could have changed quite a bit since I wrote this answer 8 years ago. Sorry, I don't think I will be much help.