# Issue scrolling UITableViewController when showing keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableViewController, and one of the custom cells contains a UITextView.  When I tap on the text view, the keyboard pops up as expected, and the table view scrolls so that the text view is visible.  So far, so good.  The problem is that the table view then scrolls again so that the text view is just below the top of the keyboard.  Here is an animated gif that demonstrates the issue captured from the simulator:

[image: animated gif demonstrating issue]

This used to not be a UITableViewController, and the scrolling was performed manually to imitate the UITableViewController behaviour.  I recently changed it to a UITableViewController embedded in a UIContainerView (to accommodate the two buttons at the bottom) and deleted all of the manual scrolling code.  The issue was also occurring before that change (and was one of the motivators for it).  Any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61875191/6314955

Answer (score 0):

Just check it out hope this works...
ViewController.h

```
    @interface MyUIViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
     UITableView *myTableView;
     UITextField *actifText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *actifText;

- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note;
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note;

@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
    @implementation MyUIViewController

@synthesize myTableView;
@synthesize actifText;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // Register notification when the keyboard will be show
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                          name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                          object:nil];

    // Register notification when the keyboard will be hide
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                          name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                          object:nil];
}

// To be link with your TextField event "Editing Did Begin"
//  memoryze the current TextField
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.actifText = textField;
}

// To be link with your TextField event "Editing Did End"
//  release current TextField
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.actifText = nil;
}

-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // Get the keyboard size
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    // Detect orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGRect frame = self.myTableView.frame;

    // Start animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

    // Reduce size of the Table view 
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.height;
    else 
        frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.width;

    // Apply new size of table view
    self.myTableView.frame = frame;

    // Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
    if (self.actifText)
      {
        CGRect textFieldRect = [self.myTableView convertRect:self.actifText.bounds fromView:self.actifText];
        [self.myTableView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:NO];
      }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // Get the keyboard size
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    // Detect orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGRect frame = self.myTableView.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

    // Increase size of the Table view 
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.height;
    else 
        frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.width;

    // Apply new size of table view
    self.myTableView.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
Swift 1.2+ version:
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var activeText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeText = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeText = nil
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(note: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            var frame = tableView.frame
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
            frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
            tableView.frame = frame
            if activeText != nil {
                let rect = tableView.convertRect(activeText.bounds, fromView: activeText)
                tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
            }
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(note: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            var frame = tableView.frame
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
            frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
            tableView.frame = frame
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, I had already tried code very similar to this.